Pac4j-core: DefaultAjaxRequestResolver.buildAjaxResponse return as null during Keycloak and Shiro integration in Apache Zeppelin
I am integrating Apache Zeppelin version 0.11.1 with Keycloak for authentication and authorization. To support this integration, I am using additional libraries (pac4j and buji pac4j) because Zeppelin uses Shiro for authentication, which does not support OIDC natively.
I have configured everything and can successfully log in to Zeppelin via Keycloak. However, after logging in, whenever I click on any section like Interpreter or Notebook Repo, I encounter a null pointer exception from pac4j-core with the following error:
HTTP ERROR 500 javax.servlet.ServletException: org.pac4j.core.exception.TechnicalException: Bad token response, error=invalid_grant, description=PKCE verification failed
URI:    /api/callback
STATUS: 500
MESSAGE:    javax.servlet.ServletException: org.pac4j.core.exception.TechnicalException: Bad token response, error=invalid_grant, description=PKCE verification failed
SERVLET:    rest
CAUSED BY:  javax.servlet.ServletException: org.pac4j.core.exception.TechnicalException: Bad token response, error=invalid_grant, description=PKCE verification failed
CAUSED BY:  org.pac4j.core.exception.TechnicalException: Bad token response, error=invalid_grant, description=PKCE verification failed
Caused by:
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.pac4j.core.exception.TechnicalException: Bad token response, error=invalid_grant, description=PKCE verification failed
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.cleanup(AdviceFilter.java:196)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:148)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:458)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:373)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:387)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:370)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.server.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:552)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1440)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1355)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:234)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.jetty.TimedHandler.handle(TimedHandler.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.pac4j.core.exception.TechnicalException: Bad token response, error=invalid_grant, description=PKCE verification failed
    at org.pac4j.oidc.credentials.authenticator.OidcAuthenticator.executeTokenRequest(OidcAuthenticator.java:206)
    at org.pac4j.oidc.credentials.authenticator.OidcAuthenticator.validate(OidcAuthenticator.java:165)
    at org.pac4j.core.client.BaseClient.lambda$retrieveCredentials$0(BaseClient.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:183)
    at org.pac4j.core.client.BaseClient.retrieveCredentials(BaseClient.java:72)
    at org.pac4j.core.client.IndirectClient.getCredentials(IndirectClient.java:145)
    at org.pac4j.core.engine.DefaultCallbackLogic.perform(DefaultCallbackLogic.java:75)
    at io.buji.pac4j.filter.CallbackFilter.doFilter(CallbackFilter.java:72)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    ... 42 more
Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.52.v20230823


This error occurs when trying to access pages like Interpreter, which should retrieve interpreter settings by calling some APIs (In the log below). These APIs are also secured by oidcSecurityFilter in my shiro.ini, causing the error mentioned above.
Here is Zeppelin's log when I access Interpreter page:
**....
**
 INFO [2024-08-08 00:10:31,281] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java[main]:271) - Done, zeppelin server started
 INFO [2024-08-08 00:10:37,513] ({qtp2142565033-27} AbstractValidatingSessionManager.java[enableSessionValidation]:233) - Enabling session validation scheduler...
 WARN [2024-08-08 00:10:45,122] ({qtp2142565033-46} TokenValidator.java[<init>]:50) - Preferred JWS algorithm: null not available. Using all metadata algorithms: [PS384, ES384, RS384, HS256, HS512, ES256, RS256, HS384, ES512, PS256, PS512, RS512]
 INFO [2024-08-08 00:10:45,765] ({qtp2142565033-35} ShiroAuthenticationService.java[<init>]:75) - ShiroAuthenticationService is initialized
 WARN [2024-08-08 00:10:45,779] ({qtp2142565033-35} SecurityRestApi.java[ticket]:82) - {"status":"OK","message":"","body":{"principal":"admin","ticket":"63f3addc-7784-414b-a4ab-c8b47837d998","roles":"[\"admin\"]"}}
 INFO [2024-08-08 00:10:46,173] ({qtp2142565033-27} NotebookServer.java[onOpen]:256) - Open connection to /127.0.0.1:2283 with Session: WebSocketSession[websocket=JsrAnnotatedEventDriver[websocket=org.apache.zeppelin.socket.NotebookServer@5a4bef8],behavior=SERVER,connection=WebSocketServerConnection@37f1a299::SocketChannelEndPoint@397c5385{l=/127.0.0.1:8080,r=/127.0.0.1:2283,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=5/300000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->WebSocketServerConnection@37f1a299[s=ConnectionState@9eec231[OPENING],f=Flusher@70a8628f[IDLE][queueSize=0,aggregateSize=-1,terminated=null],g=Generator[SERVER,validating,+rsv1],p=Parser@6ac0de89[ExtensionStack,s=START,c=0,len=0,f=null]],remote=WebSocketRemoteEndpoint@4a714423[batching=true],incoming=JsrAnnotatedEventDriver[websocket=org.apache.zeppelin.socket.NotebookServer@5a4bef8],outgoing=ExtensionStack[queueSize=0,extensions=[permessage-deflate],incoming=org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.extensions.compress.PerMessageDeflateExtension,outgoing=org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.extensions.compress.PerMessageDeflateExtension]], config: [Origin, javax.websocket.endpoint.localAddress, javax.websocket.upgrade.locales, javax.websocket.endpoint.remoteAddress, X-Watcher-Key]
 INFO [2024-08-08 00:10:54,591] ({qtp2142565033-46} AbstractValidatingSessionManager.java[enableSessionValidation]:233) - Enabling session validation scheduler...
 WARN [2024-08-08 00:10:54,595] ({qtp2142565033-32} HttpChannel.java[handleException]:776) - /next/api/interpreter
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.cleanup(AdviceFilter.java:196)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:148)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:154)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:458)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:373)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:387)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:370)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:154)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.server.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:552)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:600)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1440)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:505)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1355)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:234)
        at io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.jetty.TimedHandler.handle(TimedHandler.java:120)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:487)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:732)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:479)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:409)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.pac4j.core.http.ajax.DefaultAjaxRequestResolver.buildAjaxResponse(DefaultAjaxRequestResolver.java:42)
        at org.pac4j.core.client.IndirectClient.getRedirectionAction(IndirectClient.java:97)
        at org.pac4j.core.engine.DefaultSecurityLogic.redirectToIdentityProvider(DefaultSecurityLogic.java:237)
        at org.pac4j.core.engine.DefaultSecurityLogic.perform(DefaultSecurityLogic.java:150)
        at io.buji.pac4j.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:77)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
        ... 47 more

** ...
**
 WARN [2024-08-08 00:10:54,595] ({qtp2142565033-67} HttpChannel.java[handleException]:776) - /next/api/interpreter/repository
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.cleanup(AdviceFilter.java:196)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:148)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:154)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:458)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:373)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:387)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:370)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:154)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.server.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:552)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:600)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1440)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:505)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1355)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:234)
        at io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.jetty.TimedHandler.handle(TimedHandler.java:120)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:487)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:732)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:479)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.pac4j.core.http.ajax.DefaultAjaxRequestResolver.buildAjaxResponse(DefaultAjaxRequestResolver.java:42)
        at org.pac4j.core.client.IndirectClient.getRedirectionAction(IndirectClient.java:97)
        at org.pac4j.core.engine.DefaultSecurityLogic.redirectToIdentityProvider(DefaultSecurityLogic.java:237)
        at org.pac4j.core.engine.DefaultSecurityLogic.perform(DefaultSecurityLogic.java:150)
        at io.buji.pac4j.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:77)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
        ... 42 more
 WARN [2024-08-08 00:10:55,032] ({qtp2142565033-74} HttpChannel.java[handleException]:776) - /api/callback
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.pac4j.core.exception.TechnicalException: Bad token response, error=invalid_grant, description=PKCE verification failed
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.cleanup(AdviceFilter.java:196)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:148)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:154)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:458)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:373)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:387)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:370)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:154)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.server.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:552)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:600)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1440)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:505)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1355)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:234)
        at io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.jetty.TimedHandler.handle(TimedHandler.java:120)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:487)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:732)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:479)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.pac4j.core.exception.TechnicalException: Bad token response, error=invalid_grant, description=PKCE verification failed
        at org.pac4j.oidc.credentials.authenticator.OidcAuthenticator.executeTokenRequest(OidcAuthenticator.java:206)
        at org.pac4j.oidc.credentials.authenticator.OidcAuthenticator.validate(OidcAuthenticator.java:165)
        at org.pac4j.core.client.BaseClient.lambda$retrieveCredentials$0(BaseClient.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:183)
        at org.pac4j.core.client.BaseClient.retrieveCredentials(BaseClient.java:72)
        at org.pac4j.core.client.IndirectClient.getCredentials(IndirectClient.java:145)
        at org.pac4j.core.engine.DefaultCallbackLogic.perform(DefaultCallbackLogic.java:75)
        at io.buji.pac4j.filter.CallbackFilter.doFilter(CallbackFilter.java:72)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
        ... 42 more

Here is my shiro.ini:
[main]
roleAdminAuthGenerator = org.pac4j.core.authorization.generator.FromAttributesAuthorizationGenerator
sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager
securityManager.sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout = 86400000

oidcConfig = org.pac4j.oidc.config.OidcConfiguration
oidcConfig.discoveryURI = http://localhost:9889/realms/zeppelin/.well-known/openid-configuration
oidcConfig.clientId = zeppelin-client
oidcConfig.secret = Y44RsXalwm7ulAx5bNRukV2uEoRyPF7p
oidcConfig.clientAuthenticationMethodAsString = client_secret_basic
oidcClient = org.pac4j.oidc.client.OidcClient
oidcClient.configuration = $oidcConfig
oidcConfig.logoutUrl = http://localhost:9889/realms/zeppelin/protocol/openid-connect/logout

oidcConfig.withState = false

keycloakOidcClient = org.pac4j.oidc.client.KeycloakOidcClient
keycloakOidcClient.configuration = $oidcConfig
keycloakOidcClient.name = keycloakOidcClient
keycloakOidcClient.authorizationGenerator = $roleAdminAuthGenerator

clients = org.pac4j.core.client.Clients
clients.callbackUrl = http://localhost:8080/api/callback
clients.clients = $keycloakOidcClient

requireRoleAdmin = org.pac4j.core.authorization.authorizer.RequireAnyRoleAuthorizer
requireRoleAdmin.elements = admin_role
requireRoleUser = org.pac4j.core.authorization.authorizer.RequireAnyRoleAuthorizer
requireRoleUser.elements = admin_role, user_role

requireRoleAdmin = org.pac4j.core.authorization.authorizer.RequireAnyRoleAuthorizer

usernameAuthorizer = com.custom.pac4j.UsernameAuthorizer

config = org.pac4j.core.config.Config
config.clients = $clients
config.authorizers = username:$usernameAuthorizer

pac4jRealm = io.buji.pac4j.realm.Pac4jRealm
pac4jSubjectFactory = io.buji.pac4j.subject.Pac4jSubjectFactory
securityManager.subjectFactory = $pac4jSubjectFactory
pac4jRealm.principalNameAttribute = preferred_username

oidcSecurityFilter = io.buji.pac4j.filter.SecurityFilter
oidcSecurityFilter.config = $config
oidcSecurityFilter.clients = keycloakOidcClient

customCallbackLogic = com.custom.pac4j.ForceDefaultURLCallbackLogic
callbackFilter = io.buji.pac4j.filter.CallbackFilter
callbackFilter.defaultUrl = http://localhost:8080
callbackFilter.config = $config
callbackFilter.callbackLogic = $customCallbackLogic

logoutFilter = io.buji.pac4j.filter.LogoutFilter
logoutFilter.localLogout = true
logoutFilter.centralLogout = true
logoutFilter.config = $config
logoutFilter.defaultUrl = http://localhost:9889/realms/zeppelin/protocol/openid-connect/logout

ajaxRequestResolver = org.pac4j.core.http.ajax.DefaultAjaxRequestResolver
ajaxRequestResolver.addRedirectionUrlAsHeader = true
keycloakOidcClient.ajaxRequestResolver = $ajaxRequestResolver 

[urls]
/api/version = anon
/api/callback = callbackFilter
/api/login/logout = logoutFilter
/** = oidcSecurityFilter


As you can see, all API requests need to go through the oidcSecurityFilter in my configuration.
Libraries in use:

pac4j-core,oidc,... : version 5.7.6
javaee-pac4j-7.1.0.jar
buji-pac4j: version  8.1.0
shiro libs: 1.10.0
Zeppelin: 0.11.1

I expected the AJAX requests to retrieve the necessary data without errors, but they are returning null instead. This suggests that there may be an issue with the configuration or the way the AJAX requests are handled through the oidcSecurityFilter.

This is a quite strange. It looks like the redirectionActionBuilder is null in the buildAjaxResponse call of the DefaultAjaxRequestResolver component. Though, it should have been properly initialized at the first use.
What are the org.pac4j DEBUG logs before the error?

Yes, redirectionActionBuilder indeed init properly when I login to Zeppelin. But then when UI calls any API redirectionActionBuilder  always returns as null. So I fixed it by adding check null for redirectionActionBuilder, if it is null I will call reinit(); again in function getRedirectionAction() class IndirectClient.java.  And it works. But I don;t know if I am on the right track or not. And it still has an error left which is the first error in my quest"Caused by: org.pac4j.core.exception.TechnicalException: Bad token response, error=invalid_grant, description=PKCE verification failed"

I also check Keycloak log and I got this log: 2024-08-09 01:25:31,941 WARN [org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.utils.PkceUtils] (executor-thread-4579) PKCE verification failed. authUserId = <id>, authUsername = test 2024-08-09 01:25:31,942 WARN [org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-4579) type="CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR", realmId="<realmid>", clientId="zeppelin-client", userId="<userid>", sessionId="<sessid>", ipAddress="10.42.3.0", error="pkce_verification_failed", grant_type="authorization_code", code_id="", client_auth_method="client-secret". Do you know how to fix it. Thanks!

I have the same issue? How can this be fixed?

"pkce_verification_failed" is a bit vague: anything more relevant from DEBUG logs in Keycloak?
